# How would I make it in the text below, so that when I choose one, it will say "Wrong!" in red, or "Right!" in green?

Tags: html

I am new at coding, and just wanted to know how to make it say "Wrong!" in red or "Right!" in green.

```html
<p>Choose one:<p>

<input name="q1" type="radio" value="A">A) Luke is awesome<br>

<input name="q1" type="radio" value="B">B) Luke sucks<br>

<input name="q1" type="radio" value="C">C) Luke is mediocre<br>

<input name="q1" type="radio" value="D">D) Luke sucks so much, he has to die<br>
```

Comment: Hello Luke, welcome to coding. Few suggestions.
- You should give details in anywhere you ask your question.
- Details shows how much work and time you have put in your code so other people find value in it and means to help you.

Give more details and most of all read the stackoverflow's FAQ and moer about it (maybe i'm wrong and it's not the FAQ but do a research on how to ask questions).

After saying that, I don't understand what you mean by your question please clearify more.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use JQUERY to test the selection against the correct answer, than change the css styling accordingly. If you're new to HTML, then Jquery might be a bit of a stretch still, but there's no real way to do conditional statements in html only. You'll also want to give the options classes or id's so you can select them.

Something like this would work in Jquery;

```
$(".question1").click(function() {
   if($(this).val == "a") {
     $(this).css({"color":"green"});
   } else {
     $(this).css({"color":"red"});
   }
});
```